# Sparkfun QWIIC JST connector part number?

Tags: connector, i2c

Sparkfun promotes and I<sup>2</sup>C connector defacto standard dubbed [QWIIC](https://www.sparkfun.com/qwiic)<sup>®</sup>.   I'm looking for an orderable part number for the JST connectors that QWIIC is based on. I want to put them on a board I'm designing.

I've heard that these may be 4-pin SH connectors, and those seem close, specifically the 1mm spacing.   However, the Sparkfun pictures always show these connectors in black, while the [JST SH datasheet](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSH.pdf) says they come in natural (off-white).    Does anyone know for sure what I should layout for?

[SparkFun Humidity Sensor Breakout - SHTC3 (Qwiic)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16467)

[image: Picture of a QWIIC]

Comment: [Link to the Datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/parts/1/2/2/8/9/Qwiic_Connector_Datasheet.pdf) from Sparkfun's site. Looks like it's a SM04B-SRSS-TB, but [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SM04B-SRSS-TB-LF-SN/926710) & [Mouser](https://www.newark.com/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/sm04b-srss-tb-lf-sn/connector-header-1mm-4-position/dp/87R0314) only list them in the off-white option.

Comment: Why not just send an email to Sparkfun?

Comment: I find that mouser, digikey etc. actually stock the sparkfun SKU or the equivalent one at Adafruit. Sometimes these are in stock when the JST part isn't.

Answer (score 7):

As [brhans](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/53541/brhans) said, the QWIIC connector is compatible with the SM04B-SRSS-TB from JST, but Sparkfun has a special deal with them, so they can get them in black colour.

For compatible use you can use this:

1. Horizontal header SMT [SM04B-SRSS-TB](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SM04B-SRSS-TB-LF-SN/926875)

[image]

2. Vertical header SMT [SM04B-SRSS-TB](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/BM04B-SRSS-TB-LF-SN/926861)

[image]

3. Male connector to wire ([SHR-04V-S-B](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SHR-04V-S-B/759868))

[image]

4. Socket contact 28-32 AWG ([SSH-003T-P0.2H](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SSH-003T-P0-2-H/5725854))

[image]

The pinout is (pin 1 is on the left)

1. GND
2. 3V3
3. SDA
4. SCL

That said even at Sparkfun you find white connectors :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated [above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/558441/301846), the QWIIC connector belongs to JST SR family (with 4 positions).
In addition, the SR series IDC housings can mate with the SH series headers [(1)](https://www.digikey.co.il/en/product-highlight/j/jst/sh-and-sr-series-connectors). So, if the SM04B-SRSS-TB header connector is in sort supply, you can use a similar SH header connector variant on our PCB and still be compatible with the QWIIC standard.